# Ajax $_POST not getting set when sent to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to send some data from javascript to php with ajax post. The Ajax does succeed to run and the console.log(progData) and console.log(idData) shows the correct values. The data is just not being pushed to the php.

I've tried different dataTypes to see if that would fix it however putting it on json just broke it, even with me specifying json in the php file. I have also tried both method: 'POST' and type: 'POST'.

Here's the Ajax POST code.

```
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: './updater.php',
        data: {
            prog: progData,
            id: idData
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log("--------");
            console.log(progData);
            console.log(idData);
        }
    });
```

Here is the updater.php file code

```
    include "./database.php";
    if(isset($_POST["prog"])) {
        $prog = $_POST["prog"];
        $id = $_POST["id"];

        $sql = "UPDATE tasks SET task_progress='".  $prog ."' WHERE task_id='". $id ."'";
        if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully           ";
            echo $prog . "          ";
            echo $id;
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Prog is not set";
    }
```

What is supposed to happen when the code runs is that the two values prog and id gets sent to the php file and gets uploaded to the database. However the php file doesnt detect any $_POST and on console.log(data) it shows that the $_POST["prog"] isnt set. According to the Network tab the data is getting sent correctly to the php.

Comment: method should be type

Comment: you're also open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: There are also syntax errors in your PHP script (e.g. `echo $prog + "          ";` < that's JS concatenation) ... and I don't think `$prog = $_POST["prog"] or $_REQUEST["prog"];` will do what you think it will (again, PHP isn't JS).

Comment: Just open developer console(F12) and move to Network tab. Then click on the button to post and check if data is passed or not. Or just post a screenshot of that request.

Comment: According to that the form data does get sent.

Comment: what values are you sending via the two input variables `progData` and `idData`? Simple integers, strings or other such as array / object?

Comment: Can you show what you see in the network panel? Request headers & data.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. What happened is that the data would get sent to "updater.php" and then the .htaccess would redirect it to "updater" creating a "Status code: 302 found" and then I guess the data gets lost somewhere in between. Removing the .php and having it go directly to "updater" fixed it.

Comment: That is why I told you to look into network panel , this error took my whole 3 days to resolve dated back in 2016. 
302 Redirect issue.

Comment: Yeah thank you. Havn't really used the Networks tab before